# Searching a file in google drive using google api (python)

Tags: python, google-api

I am trying to search a file in my Google Drive. I gave the file name and file ID but it shows some error in `drive_service`.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import io
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
try:
    import argparse
    flags = \
    argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')

creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = (tools.run_flow(flow, store,
             flags) if flags else tools.run(flow, store))
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

id = '0B1hy3tfpHf5WSkNLNFJXVS04Qlk'
name = 'hello.txt'
page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='image/jpeg'",
            spaces='drive', fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
            pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):

        # Process change

        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'
              )))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

I got the error as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "searchfilev3.py", line 27, in 
>           response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='image/jpeg'",
>       NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct API? Have you tried [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) one?

Comment: yes,i think so...Is there anything wrong?

Comment: There the file is fetched using: `service.files()`. Also try importing the full `http` module using: `from apiclient import http`.

Comment: you need to define a drive_service which has been authenticated to access the google drive account.

Comment: how to define it i am new to this Google API coding(python too).Can you explain me please.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to generate a credential to authorize your request. See here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library. The code below uses a service account key which you store in client_secret.json.

   ```
   scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
   credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
   http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())        
   drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

to

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

AND change

```
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
```

to

```
store = file.Storage('token.json')
```